# Что остается в памяти вместе с сервисом?

Tags: android

Есть главная Activity со статической переменной. Есть Service, в котором при запуске открывается отдельный поток.

В потоке я оперирую со статической переменной. И когда закрываю приложение (сервис остается работать), ошибки не возникает. Значит остается работать не только сервис, но и само приложение не закрывается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервис - часть приложения и сам по себе работать не может. Все необходимые ему классы и ресурсы остаются в памяти или подгружаются по мере надобности.

Comment: сервис это компонент приложения и он легко может жить в отдельном процессе, более того сервис создан для возможности межпроцессорного взаимодействия (IPC). В данной ситуации это StrongReference на компонент Activity и они в 1 процесее, а референс держит его. Это очень плохо на практике так ненадо делать. Ибо Activity попадает в псевдо LRU-cache, которая зависит от системы. Нужно или изменить логику и переменную хранить внутри сервиса (что тоже плохо) или забиндить сервис. Вот здесь немного про это есть https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle

Comment: А хорошим ли вариантом будет передавать данные в Activity через EventBus? На данный момент, я использую его для того, чтобы просто сигнализировать активности, что можно забрать свежие данные из статической переменной.